# Cocos2d-x How to list all files from a resource directory

Tags: c++, file, resources, cocos2d-x

How to list all files from a resource directory?

I'm using c++ and need a way read all the files from a resource directory and push to a vector.

ex:

```
cards/
 card_1.png
 card_414.png
 card_6124.png
 card_2.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think there is no available API in cocos2dx.

it's easy to implement by native code.